# In bash, how do I use grep to find a certain function from the output of perldoc?

Tags: grep

So I want to find a certain built in function for Perl. I am running Ubuntu, I run this line in terminal:

```
$ perldoc perlfunc | grep "map"
```

But I don't get the documentation for that function, am I using grep wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `grep` at all? Why not just `perldoc perlfunc`?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker You need a `-f`, but yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep finds individual lines, which won't help you much.

Use e.g.

```
perldoc -f map
```

To see doc for a given built-in.

(And `perldoc perldoc` to see the doc for perldoc.)